# Length of last frame with AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cgimage, avassetwriter

I'm trying to create a video from frames of `CGImage`s, it works great but I'm trying to have the last frame stay on screen longer, iI tried setting the end of video time with `endSessionAtSourceTime:` but it still ends too quickly. I ended up adding the last frame a second time which fixed it but it doesn't seem like the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's not what endSessionAtSourceTime is for. You either need to set the duration of that last frame's sample to something longer than every other sample, (which makes the recording variable-frame rate which some software does not like), or simply keep adding that last sample over and over again with the same single-frame duration until you reach the desired total amount of time.